# How to find the largest outline using Emgu (c #) with one line of code like python opencv

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, contour

Here is my current code in C# using the Emgu library :

```cs
int largest_contour_index = 0;
double largest_area = 0;
Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfPoint largestContour3;

for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; ++i){
    double contourArea = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]); // Find the area of contour
    if (contourArea > largest_area)
    {
         largest_area = contourArea;
         largest_contour_index = i; // Store the index of largest contour
    }
}
largestContour = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfPoint(contours[largest_contour_index].ToArray());
```

and I will want to find a solution to write it on a single line like the following code in python and Opencv if there is a way on C #

```py
largestContour = max(contour, key=cv.contourArea)
```

Comment: I think in C# iterating through all the countours and storing the largest area is completely ok. There is no similar to opencv one line max()

Comment: @demonplus, i thanks u for your response :), between, max() is not opencv function but python function :)

Comment: Agree, in C# you could  use LINQ Max() instead but I doubt it would be better than initial version

Comment: Okey, Thank u ;)